# Can't open MvvmCross sln in monodevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, mvvmcross

I'm trying to build a x-platform mobile app using mvmmx. I'm starting from md and not vs, as my primary target is iOS. I'm running into a few issues:

- I can't any of the MvvmX sln file in md. md opens them as binary files.
- if I include some of the project in my solution, I'm having build issues.

Versions:

- md 3.0.5
- MvvmX: vNext, fresh clone of today

Is this a known issue, or am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the very latest build of MonoDevelop - from the alpha stream.

Or change the v12 to v11 in the first row of the sln file.

This bugs been around since May - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4919 - but it is almost in the GA release...